# How to get changed CKEditor element

Tags: ckeditor, onchange, addeventlistener

Is there any event that is fired when there is a change inside custom div?I don't want to listen for editor.on('change'), but only to detect in which dom element the change is taking place, (removed or inserted character). For example:

```
 var template = new CKEDITOR.template(
        '<div class="layout-container">\
                    <div class="layout-column-content" >\
                        <p>content</p>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>'
);

var layoutElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(template);
editor.insertElement(layoutElement);
```

Adds custom layout.User types in it and i want to see what is he typing without traversing the whole dom. I tried to add listeners to the div but it seems that CKEditor cleans them. Any clever solutions?

Edit:
This plugin http://ckeditor.com/addon/elementspath is probable workaround:
i have solved my problem with this snippet:

```
   editor.on('elementsPathUpdate', function(event) {
        elementsList = editor._.elementsPath.list;
    });
```

combined with the change event.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i know is this plugin: http://alfonsoml.blogspot.de/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html

Comment: I know it too, but it listens only for change and fires an event, it does not give info in which dom element the change is happening.

Comment: Download the plugin and read its code. Using the Mutation Observer listener you can get all the info about any change in the editor

Comment: @AlfonsoML Hi Alfonso. If you don't mind and have some time, could you show me a example about how to do exactly what the OP want? I'm also interested in this. Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: Download the plugin, read its code and use it. if you want to adjust it, then read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver